# Android, is there a way to update a Fabric Beta distributed app within the app?

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I have successfully distributed the app via fabric beta, but after the new version of the app was distributed, there is no window for updates in the old app.

Is there a way to update a Fabric Beta distributed app within the app?

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

In the project, I have integrated the fabric, like this:

build:
1：

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

2:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
}
}
```

3:

```
dependencies {
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Fastfile:

```
fastlane_version "2.68.0"

generated_fastfile_id "1111"

default_platform :android

lane :beta do
   build_android_app(task: "assembleRelease")
   emails = ["xxxxx"]

   sh("touch changelog.txt")
   File.write("./changelog.txt","Distributed with fastlane")

   # upload to Beta by Crashlytics
   crashlytics(
       notes_path:"fastlane/changelog.txt",
       api_token: "xxxx",
       build_secret:"xxxx",
       emails: emails,
       groups:[], 
       notifications: true
  )end
```

Fabric.properties

```
apiSecret=xxxx
apiKey=xxxx
```

Comment: My phone model is Samsung Galaxy S7 edge.

Comment: Hey Alice, Thanks for all of the details. I work on Fabric and Firebase, do you mean you're not seeing the notification in the Notifications view when there is a new version of your app?

Comment: Hi, Mike, Thank you for answering my question. Now, when my app has a new version, the notifications in the notification will only show up when I open the beta app. I want to know if there will be an updated notification in the app when I run the old app?

Comment: Gotcha, we look for a new build every two hours on Android. If you launch the app before that window, then we may not display the notification or it may not appear until you do the launch. We do this in order to ensure we're not checking too frequently on user's devices.

Comment: How is this update information displayed? Displayed through the system notification center or via the prompts in app, just like in an iOS app.

Comment: Via the System Notification Center. We don't have an in-app update on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric and Firebase here. On Android, Fabric checks every two hours to see if a new version of your app is available. If so, it will show the notifications in the System Notifications center. There is not an in-app update prompt on Android.

Comment: would it be possible to add it manually? i.e. do a check from an app and if so either trigger upfate instantly OR redirect to beta page